# Makefile with auto-dependencies

Tags: c, makefile

Suppose we have following set up:

## prog.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "prog.h"

int main(){
        printf("%s\n", HELLO);

        return 0;
}
```

## prog.h

```
#ifndef _PROG_H
#define _PROG_H

#define HELLO "hello world"

#endif
```

## Makefile

(note I simplified the Makefile in order the problem to be more visible)

```
MYCC    = gcc

CC      = $(MYCC) -MMD -MP -c

LINK    = $(MYCC) -o

TARGETS = prog

all:    $(TARGETS)

clean:
        rm -f *.o *.d $(TARGETS)

prog: prog.o
        $(LINK) $@ $^

%.o: %.c
        $(CC) $<

-include $(SRC:%.c=%.d)
```

This makefile suppose to auto create dependencies (*.d files) after first run.

However something is wrong, because if I change the .h file, it will not rebuild the project at all.

```
[nmmm@zenbook ctest]$ make
gcc -MMD -MP -c prog.c
gcc -o prog prog.o
[nmmm@zenbook ctest]$ ./prog 
hello world
[nmmm@zenbook ctest]$ touch prog.c 
[nmmm@zenbook ctest]$ make
gcc -MMD -MP -c prog.c
gcc -o prog prog.o
[nmmm@zenbook ctest]$ touch prog.h
[nmmm@zenbook ctest]$ make    << here is the problem
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
```

`prog.d` looks correct.

Anything I am doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Makefile auto-dependency with gcc include h file inside include](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32199539/makefile-auto-dependency-with-gcc-include-h-file-inside-include)

Comment: You should either: delete your old question and post a new one, or edit your old question, but not post a new one. Posting two questions does not increase the quality of the site.

Comment: old question deleted.

Comment: amongst other things:  the compile rule needs to list the header file as a dependancy.   I've never known the #include statement to actually create the dependancy files.  rather a rule is needed that uses either a call to sed or a call to gcc with the appropriate parameters.   And to avoid rebuilding the dependancy files when 'make clean' is invoked, something like: 'ifneq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "clean"
-include $(DEP)
endif' is needed.  the compile rule needs '%.d' added as a dependancy; where $(DEP) is a macro containing the list of dependancy file names

Comment: suggest this line: '$(CC) $<'  be replaced with something like: '$(CC) $(CCFLAGS)  $< -o $@ -I. '

Comment: the posted makefile is also missing the statement: .PHONY: all clean  so make will try to create files with those names and should output messages about not being able to create those files.

Comment: in general, when invoking a utility, like gcc, the macro CC should be set to the whole path to the utility, not depend on the $(PATH) to include the path to the utility.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never actually define `SRC` anywhere. If you either explicitly set it:

```
SRC = prog.c
```

or use a wildcard:

```
SRC = $(wildcard *.c)
```

then everything works for me.

Comment: thanks, can you tell me if this src supports wildcared? can i put *.c there?

Comment: @Nick Not just `*.c`, you'd have to use the `wildcard` function. Updated my answer to illustrate.